# The inability to comment because of low reputation is a stupid stupid design flaw

Tags: discussion

If I can answer a question why in the world can't I comment on a question? I have a question for someone and instead of doing the intelligent thing and asking for more info I'm forced to ask for more info in the Answer box. Annoying. Stupid and annoying.

For example:

[How to transform World data from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61816/how-to-transform-world-data-from-epsg-4326-to-epsg-3857/61821#61821)

Comment: it is by design - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9701/why-cant-i-comment-on-this-answer

Comment: More to the point is [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment).  Note that several respondents are on the SE team.

Comment: well, everything else about the design of this site is damn brilliant, so I guess you just need to suffer through the occasional peculiarity.

Comment: We're not defending the *status quo*, we're just telling you what it is.  The main point is that you are bringing up something beyond the control of the GIS community: this issue needs to be discussed on meta SO, and has been. No amount of discussion here will do any good.

Comment: Ah, groovy. I'll take my whinging to them. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Well at least you have the rep to upvote [answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/61591/2856) now ;)

Answer (score 9):

Best advice: Put aside the frustration and concentrate on contributing one or two good answers or questions and in very short order you'll be over the no-comment barrier.

---

I remember the pain of the comment limitation, but the consequence of enabling comments for new users is greater than the pain dealing with the noise of new users who don't yet understand what makes Stack Exchange different from the discussion platforms that have come before. At least that's the conclusion by the developers at Stack Exchange central, and we don't have a choice about that.

This has been discussed at great length on Meta Stack Overflow, though I can't locate the specific ones I remember right now. Here is a starting point:
[How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

If you can come up with a well-reasoned and well-researched alternative you are welcome to propose it, here or on http://meta.stackoverflow.com with the `feature-request` tag. It won't get any serious attention unless you put a *lot* work into the proposal though, because there is so much history in this [feature/bug] already.

The bottom line is that the commenting system has had a lot of careful thought put into it, and it will take a lot more thought to adjust it.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I understand that this is a convention that has worked well for them, so I'll just roll with it. I just remember going through the same thing on stackoverflow and seeing it still in place pushed me to write something.